# Excel / VBAfrom x language to english version

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to run a VBA / Excel program on 2 different pc's.
One is with the dutch version of Excel (VB 7) and one with the english one (VB 6.5).

When i try to run a function, i get the error:

```
 Run-time error '32809':
 Application-defined or object-defined error
```

When i strip down all code to just displaying a msgbox, the error still persists.
When i create a new tab, that tab can execute code.

I suppose this has something to do with wrong translation?

Any help on this? 
Thanks!

Comment: yes, it could be a language issue. make sure that your functions have unique names, as a word in English may coincide to be a function name in Dutch. for example, 'die' has different meanings to each (sterven or that)

Comment: Be also aware that the automatic names that Excel generates for Sheets and shapes get translated to the language of the excel application that opens the file.

Comment: I think the problem could lay with the sheetnames, as the sheetname is still the dutch one..

Comment: You also should show us some code so that we could try to understand where your issue comes from

Comment: I agree with @Jmax here. Show us the offending line of code. That ways you can get quick help and we don't have to play the guess game ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:
Store you excel file as .xls and not as .xlsm

Thanks team :)